# HttpApplication does not quit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a single page app with Angular.js front, web api2 back end, also using Castle Windsor and SignalR.

I am using a c# component on the server that maintains server state. So, on Application_Start() I register the main component with Castle Windsor as Singleton.

```
IoC.Container.Register(Component.For(typeof(MainManager)).ImplementedBy(typeof(MainManager)).LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

(however, I tested PerWebRequest and few other lifestyles, but the main problem remains the same, the started task does not quit)

Then in my Web Api, I can execute commands against that instance.

```
[HttpGet]
public void StartProcess(Params p) {
  IoC.Resolve<MainManager>().StartOperation(p);
}
```

and this also gives me opportunity to stop it from the website by calling another controller method

```
[HttpGet]
public void Stop() {
  IoC.Resolve<MainManager>().RequestStop();
}
```

This works great for the most part. However, sometimes my application gets in a bad state (for a multitude of reasons, It can get restarted in prod) I can emulate this problem by modifying web.config during running the operation, so a lot of things reset (such as Signal-R connection), but the main operation does not stop running.

(In fact, once my application is in bad state I can no longer call that Stop controller method because MainManager has been reset, so the only way to stop it as of now is to reset the whole IIS. This is certainly not desired)

I am trying to figure out how to detect this state, and terminate the running process.

As one possible solution, I am experimenting with using *Bound* lifestyle (new in Castle Windsor 3), trying to scope my manager to my web api httpapplication, but no luck yet.

**update**

I tried making the main task method static

```
[HttpGet]
public void Start(ForceData data) {
  MainManager.Start(data);
}
```

I believe this should take out the singleton instance out of equation, but the code still runs un-interrupted after touching web.config

**update**

took the MainManager class out of equation. All my web api method does now is loop + sleep

```
[HttpGet]
public void Start(ForceData data) {
  foreach (var e in data.Members)
  {
    _log.Info("processing member: {0}", e.Email);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

this loop is also not interrupted after touching web.config.

So, at this point I am reading about MVC [request lifecycle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741228/MVC-Application-Lifecycle) to figure out at which point this request goes zombie rouge

Comment: change threads so that they have `IsBackground` set to true. `MainManager.Stop()` will stop them gracefully during normal exits, and `thread.IsBackground` will make sure that the app can shutdown if something fails.

Comment: @jgauffin I am not explicitly spawning any threads.. Are you saying i should start doing that in order to set that property?

Comment: background thread would work, but if i have to spawn a new thread, that will change things such as identity/security. My application currently relies on httpcontext etc.. is it possible to create a background thread with everything else identical as current thread ?

Comment: credentials are automatically copied to new threads (unsure about impersonation)

Comment: @jgauffin not httpcontext. I tried assigning that manually but it doesn't seem to be that easy

Comment: No. The HttpContext is disposed when the request ends. You have to perform it directly in the controller action or switch to use asynchronous action methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, as HttpApplication instances are not freed immediately when application restarts,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

> When an application restart is required, ASP.NET will serve all pending requests from the existing application domain and the old assemblies before restarting the application domain and loading the new assemblies.

In all your sample Web API method, you can see the thread is still busy, which means ASP.NET runtime considers this request is still being processed.

Comment: do you know of a way to detect this? Application_End is not triggered

Comment: As the same article implicitly states, `Application_End` is called only when all pending requests are served. Thus, it would be pretty difficult for your application to detect the restart.  Generally speaking, you should give up your current synchronous approach, and test if the async support helps in such case, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4 and http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2. They should allow you to better control your tasks.